# How to increase length of body Matter.js?

Tags: javascript, game-physics, p5.js, matter.js

I want to increase the length of a rectangle body in matter.js making it longer. However using the scale() method can only change it on a y and x axis scale. This is a problem when My rectangle is rotated and its length will will changing constantly. How can I go about doing this in matter.js and p5.js?

Comment: Matter.js only works on the x and y axes since it's a 2d physics engine, so that's all of the scaling that's possible, if I understand correctly.